# Launch doom-emacs with options of main and #1

Tags: start-up

Upon launching doom-emacs, it displays

[image]

What does the options `main` and `#1` mean?

It toggle [2] as default, how could I toggle [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfcco.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are your open workspaces. Workspace #1 is named "main". Workspace #2 is named "#1" (new workspaces are named in this format: `#N`). Workspace #2 is active (hence it's highlighting).

You can switch to workspaces 1 via <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>meta</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> or (for non-evil users) <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>.

You can get this display by pressing <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> (or <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> for non-evil users), both are bound to `+workspace/display`.

This functionality is provided by the `:ui workspaces` module, which is configured to auto-display your workspaces (like you see) whenever a new workspace is created (one is created every time you open a new frame so you have a fresh workspace per frame).

Here are some other things you can do with workspaces:

- For evil users:

  - You can switch workspaces with <kbd>meta</kbd><kbd>1..9</kbd>
  - You can switch workspaces by name (with completion) with <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>
  - Create a new workspace: <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>meta</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, or `M-x +workspace/new`)
  - Delete the current workspace: <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> or `M-x +workspace/delete`
  - Rename the current workspace: <kbd>SPC</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
  - A comprehensive list of keybinds is available [here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/config/default/+evil-bindings.el#L341-L357) and [here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/config/default/+evil-bindings.el#L547-L571)
- For non-evil users

  - You can switch workspaces with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>1..9</kbd>
  - You can switch workspaces by name (with completion) with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>
  - Create a new workspace: <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>
  - Delete the current workspace: <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>
  - Rename the current workspace: <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
  - A comprehensive list of keybinds is available [here](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/develop/modules/config/default/+emacs-bindings.el#L157-L182)

Hope that helps!